# Restrict a Django REST framework generic view to a set of HTTP methods

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

With function-based views you can restrict a view to some HTTP methods like so:

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def view(request):
    ...
```

which is neat and explicit. Is there a native way to do the same for a generic view without resorting to `if self.request.method == ...` conditions?

Comment: Many of the generic views will have this impliciltly builf in. ListViews should be GET only. Update views should accets POST's.  Delete should accept deletes...

Comment: I just wanted to disallow OPTIONS for `ListCreateAPIView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply add: `http_method_names` like in standard Django View:

Example:

```
class MyView(ListAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    # ...
```

Answer (score 3):

One just needs to set `http_method_names` attribute on the generic view's class:

```
class MyListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    http_method_names = ["get", "post"]
    ...
```

Curiously enough, `http_method_names` is not documented in relation to class-based or generic views either in [Class Based Views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) nor [Generic Views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) sections of the API Guide.

Comment: But all views are Django based views so documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.http_method_names